# nodejs not sending response to reactjs when i use url http://localhost:3000/dashboard

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to nodejs and Reactjs. I had created an sample project with reactjs and nodesjs. if I enter with http://localhost:3000, the app working fine, request and response b/w nodejs and reactjs works fine. If I directly enter with http://localhost:3000/dashboard, it sends response directly to browser and displaying

```
{
merchantid: "Not login"
}
```

In nodejs I have added middleware authentication and saved token in cookies. If user directly enters url http://localhost:3000/dashboard and he was not login then I wanted to redirect him to login page. My problem here is my reactjs not receiving the response.

Nodejs login when /dasboard page entered directly

```
router.get('/dashboard', merchantAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if(!req.merchant){
      throw new Error(': merchantid: Not login')
    } 
   } 
   catch (e) {
    const errors = errorhandle(e)
    res.status(400).send(errors)
   }
});
```

Reactjs to call get request

```
axios
            .get('http://localhost:3000/dashboard')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('response: ', response)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('err response data: ', err)
                const {merchantid} = err.response.data
                if (merchantid){
                    this.props.history.push("/")
                }
            })
```

browser message. this browser message I should get in react js and I, based on the error I will format and will display to the end user.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using res.redirect('/') when user directly enters /dashboard url and he was not logged in previously.